# Can't assign operator but need to have a variable on left side of assignment

Tags: python

```
     def save_in_field(self, fieldname, filename, extension):
        self.instance.image_main = self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + filename + extension
```

and then:

```
def execute(self):
    for key, value in self.sizes.items():
        # Save images in fields
        self.save_in_field(key, key, '.png')
```

Problem is that I need 'image_main' in a for loop to be a variable with its value changed at each iteration.
Concatenation doesn't work, so what's the proper way to handle this case ?

Comment: Without more code, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Is this about dynamic variable names?

Comment: I edited the code. Yes, it should be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var = 'image_main'
self.instance[var]
```

Comment: thanks, it says that the model object does not support item assignment.